# MySQL: Is it okay when three proses simultaneusly (INSERT, SELECT, INSERT)?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, simultaneous

I have table `Context` and `Criteria` with many-to-many relationship, so I created `DetailsContext` table that stored ID from each table.

Then, `Context` table is empty and `Criteria` is master table

I have form to insert a context, firstly I inserted `Context` table to get an ID (autoincrement) than I selected ID table `Context` and `Criteria` by order ID DESC to get latest ID. Then I inserted to `DetailsContext` table.

Is't ok I just use `SELECT ID FROM CONTEXT ORDER BY ID DESC` to get latest ID? I afraid it didn't work when many users is accessed together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then according to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html), you can get the last ID that was inserted into the table with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` as long as the id is autogenerated and you are inserting one row per `INSERT` statement.